# Segmentation fault while trying to insert a word into trie

Tags: c++, pointers, trie

Hi :) Could anyone tell me why the following code doesn't work? The program crashes at the `if(children[word[letter_no] - 'A'] == nullptr)` line in node corresponding to `'B'`. But the node **is** created, and when I try to call `children[1]` in the constructor, it works. But when it's called in `insert()` function, it doesn't...

## include

```
#include <memory> //shared_ptr
#include <string>    
using namespace std;    
const int ALPHABET = 26;

class Node {
public:
    shared_ptr<Node> children[ALPHABET];
    
    Node() { for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET; ++i) children[i] = nullptr;}
    void insert(const string &word, unsigned letter_no) {
        if (letter_no < word.length()) {
            if (children[word[letter_no] - 'A'] == nullptr) 
                children[word[letter_no] - 'A'] = make_shared<Node>();
            children[word[letter_no] - 'A']->insert(word, letter_no+1);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Node trie{};
    trie.insert("ABC", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do note that letters are not mandated to be in a contiguous range like numbers are.  If for example the system used EBCDIC (which it could) then this would not work.

Comment: Off topic, but blank lines and brackets are free!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Enable your compiler warnings!**

- You got *undefined behavior* due to unspecified order of evaluation:

  ```
  children[word[letter_no] - 'A']->insert(word, ++letter_no);
  ```

  > warning: unsequenced modification and access to `letter_no` [-Wunsequenced]
- You also have a potentially dangerous comparison here:

  ```
  letter_no < word.length
  ```

  > warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions

[**on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GjBCBS9yYrXVPdKR)

---

Also, you should not use `new` and `delete` in modern C++ code. Use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` depending on what ownership semantics you require.

---

From the comments:

> **Jecke**: That's all true, but none of it is what's causing the problem. I simplified my code so it would be more readable in a question. In my original code, I'm trying to use shared_ptr, but the result is the same. Look, pastebin.com/MFZdrp22 doesn't work any better (still segmentation fault)

Look carefully at these lines:

```
if (letter_no < word.length()) 
{
    if (children[word[letter_no] - 'A'] == nullptr)
    {
        children[word[letter_no] - 'A'] = make_shared<Node>();
    }

    ++letter_no;                                              // (0)
    children[word[letter_no] - 'A']->insert(word, letter_no); // (1)
}
```

- `word` is `"ABC"`.
- `word[letter_no] - 'A'` is `0`.
- At **(0)**, you increment `letter_no`.
- At **(1)**, `word[letter_no] - 'A'` is `1`.
- `children[1]` is `nullptr`. **Boom!**

Again, **the compiler is your friend**. Compile with `-fsanitize=undefined` and you'll get the following error message:

```
runtime error: member call on null pointer of type 'Node'
runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'Node'
```

[**on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/M1Yiw4BVIBz6B8Az)

Comment: And if OP eliminated code duplication problem would disappear

Comment: That's all true, but none of it is what's causing the problem. I simplified my code so it would be more readable in a question. In my original code, I'm trying to use shared_ptr, but the result is the same. Look, http://pastebin.com/MFZdrp22 doesn't work any better (still segmentation fault)

Comment: @Jecke: read lines 18 and 19 carefully. You're accessing a `nullptr`! What you probably want is `children[word[letter_no] - 'A']->insert(word, letter_no + 1);`

Comment: @Jecke: if you feel like my answer solved your problems you should **mark it as accepted**.

Answer (score 2):

Vittorio already answered about reason couple words about style:

you can have only one method:

```
void insert(const string &word, size_t letter_no = 0);
```

then you do not need override, you can use `std::unique_ptr` and you do not need loop in your ctor, and if you eliminate code duplication:

```
    if (letter_no < word.length()) {
        auto &child = children[word[letter_no] - 'A'];
        if ( !child ) 
            child = std::make_unique<Node>();
        child->insert(word, ++letter_no);
    }
```

that would not only make your code more readable but woul make your problem disappear

Answer (score 0):

[Vittorio Romeo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42160817/2642059) is correct. You should always clean up your warnings.

But in the intent of giving you a full explanation:

Consider when your 1<sup>st</sup> recursion, `letter_no` is `0`. `word` contains `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, and `'\0'`. So `letter_no` indexes the `'A'`.

After validating that `letter_no` is a valid index into `word`: `letter_no < word.length()` you *increment* `letter_no`: `children[word[letter_no] - 'A']->insert(word, ++letter_no);`

`letter_no` is incremented as the 1<sup>st</sup> operation on this line, so it actually has value `1`, indexing the `'B'`. Which you then subtract by `'A'` giving you the index of `1`, which is an unallocated element.

---

As far as a solution, you don't care about maintaining `letter_no`'s value, so just do this: `children[word[letter_no] - 'A']->insert(word, letter_no + 1);`